# settings.Database improperly configured. switching to psql from sqlite

Tags: django, database, settings, psql

Getting this error - ImproperlyConfigured at /boards/

settings.DATABASES is improperly configured. Please supply the NAME value.

```
DATABASES   

{'default': {'ATOMIC_REQUESTS': False,
             'AUTOCOMMIT': True,
             'CONN_MAX_AGE': 0,
             'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
             'HOST': 'localhost',
             'NAME': '',
             'OPTIONS': {},
             'PASSWORD': '********************',
             'PORT': '',
             'TEST': {'CHARSET': None,
                      'COLLATION': None,
                      'MIRROR': None,
                      'NAME': None},
             'TIME_ZONE': None,
             'USER': ''}}
```

I'm using dj_database_url,

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': dj_database_url.config(
        default=config('DATABASE_URL')
    )
}
```

I was having some errors when my production db is psql and my dev is sqlite - so i figured i'd make it all psql. I copied my .env from prod to the local, and i think i messed up there. it currently looks like:

```
DATABASE_URL=postgres://test:test@localhost:5432/test
ALLOWED_HOSTS=.localhost,127.0.0.1
```

No idea what to do from here. I'm definitely missing something that's probably obvious.

Answer (score 0):

You're missing the Name value as it says in the error. You need to provide the database name. You're also missing the POST and USER values, which I believe are required.

- NAME = the name of the database
- USER = your database username
- PORT = port number